Plotting streamlines, streaklines, and pathlines for a velocity field
I'm trying to create an educational notebook with the Computational Essay template to show the importance of different fluid flow visualization techniques for a Fluid Mechanics class. Specifically, I want to create diagrams for a vector field, streamlines, streaklines, and pathlines for the following 2D time-dependent velocity field,
$$
\vec{V}=u_0\text{sin}\left(\omega\left(t-\frac{y}{v_0}\right)\right)\hat{i}+v_0\hat{j}
$$
where $u_0$, and $v_0$ are constant initial velocities, and $\omega$ is a constant frequency of oscillation. For instructional ease, I just set $u_0=v_0=1$ and $\omega=\pi$.
The velocity field and streamlines are the easy part because I know of Mathematica commands to directly plot them. For example, my vector field (where u represents $u_0$ and v is $v_0$):
Manipulate
VectorPlot[{u*Sin[\[Omega]*(t - y/v)], v}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "Velocity Magnitude"],
FrameLabel -> {x, y}], {t, 0, 10}]

For streamlines, I just change the plot command to StreamPlot. But for streaklines and pathlines, I do not know how to create a plot that represents them. For an overview just so we're on the same page, there's a useful gif on this Wikipedia page. The gist is:

Pathlines: A line traced by a given particle as it flows from one point to another in the flow (think of a dye that has been released and you trace the dye as it moves).
Streaklines: A line which consists of all particles in a flow that have previously passed through a common point (think of dye being continuously released at a single point, say the origin, and trace a line of where that dye is going).

I know Plot can create a line of the velocity vector, but I don't know how to make that line increase in length as time progresses (as if it were dye released say for a streakline), nor do I know how to make a dye "point" which moves with the flow direction and is traced in time (for a pathline). Anyone have thoughts on how to create these two plots?
Thanks in advance for any tips or ideas.

You can use NDSolve using as initial condition each point whose path you wish to trace.

@MichaelE2 I thought NDSolve was only for differential equations though? Do you mean NSolve? Either way, I don't quite know how to use them to solve for a point whose path I want to trace.

Streamlines etc. are the solutions to differential equations. In fact, StreamPlot calls NDSolve.

Actually, DSolve[{x'[t], y'[t]} == {u*Sin[\[Omega]*(t - y[t]/v)], v}, {x, y}, t] gives a symbolic general solution, which could be used to plot any such line.

Thanks for your reminder about streamlines, I forgot about that! It's gotten me so far to the following: sol = DSolve[{{x'[t],y'[t]} == {u*Sin[\[Omega]*(t - y[t]/v)], v}, {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}}, {x, y}, t] which of course changing the initial conditions of x[0] and y[0] produce different results that I can then plot with something like: Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]. I'm not sure this solution procedure entirely makes sense though because a pathline for example, isn't necessarily tangent to the flow direction whereas a streamline would be.

Maybe Plothighlighting with a Placed effect which varies for time makes more sense? Or maybe ParametricPlot?
